# How to read the public URL in GWT?

Tags: java, url, gwt

I m new in GWT and I m generating a web application in which i have to create a public URL.
In this public URL i have to pass hashtag(#) and some parameters.

I am finding difficulty in achieving this task.

1. Extracting the hashtag from the URL.
2. Extracting the userid from the URL.

My public URL example is  :: http://www.xyz.com/#profile?userid=10003

Comment: i dont understand, you want to create or read an URL?

Comment: i want to read the URL

Comment: if i understood you correctly, get yourself familiar with `Place`

Answer (score 0):

To get the parameters:

```
String userId = Window.Location.getParameter("userid");
```

To get the anchor / hash tag:
I don't think there is something, you can parse the URL: look at the methods provided by [Window.Location](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.Location.html).

Comment: when i try to use this String userId = Window.Location.getParameter("userId");
 
it gives null

Comment: have you tried 

    <http://www.xyz.com?userid=10003>

In which mode are trying to run it, here is an example I use for calling:

    http://127.0.0.1:8888/Sign_up.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997&userId=J

Comment: @kushal: try: Window.Location.getParameter("userid");

Answer (score 0):

To access the URL in GWT you can use the History.getToken() method. It will give you the entire string that follows the hashtag ("#").
In your case (http://www.xyz.com/#profile?userid=10003) it will return a string "profile?userid=10003". After you have this you can parse it however you want. You can check if it contains("?") and u can split it by "?" or you can get a substring. How you get the information from that is really up to you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you already have the URL. I'm not that good at Regex, but this should work:

```
        String yourURL = "http://www.xyz.com/#profile?userid=10003";
        String[] array = yourURL.split("[\\p{Lower}\\p{Upper}\\p{Punct}}]");
        int userID = 0;
        for (String string : array) {
            if (!string.isEmpty()) {
                userID = Integer.valueOf(string);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(userID);
```